# video playing issue in ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

some youtube videos working and some are not working.all are working fine in youtube but in my app that issue occuring.
Here is my code:

```
string url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + AppSettings.YoutubeUri;
        AppSettings.LinkUrl = url;
        AppSettings.LinkUrl=AppSettings.LinkUrl.Replace("&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0", "").Replace("http://www.youtube.com/v/", "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=");

        System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient ();
        string _html  = wc.DownloadString(AppSettings.LinkUrl);
            AppSettings.YoutubeUri=DownloadManagerHelper.GetYotubeUrl(_html);




        webView.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false;
        webView.MediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay = true;
        webView.ScalesPageToFit=true;
        webView = new UIWebView (View.Bounds);
        webView.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl (AppSettings.YoutubeUri)));
        View.AddSubview (webView);
```

so how to solve this issue please help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

[YTPlayer](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) is a control i have used in iOS for playing youtube videos. You may have a try to [this for Xamarin](https://github.com/afalz/YTHelper).

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:**

```
 // Youtube video ID
 NSString *videoId = @"M7lc1UVf-VE";

  // For a full list of player parameters, see the documentation for the HTML5 player
  // at: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?playerVersion=HTML5
  NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
      @"controls" : @0,
      @"playsinline" : @1,
      @"autohide" : @1,
      @"showinfo" : @0,
      @"modestbranding" : @1
  };

   // Pass video id to YTPlayerView object, and pass parameters to it
  [self.playerView loadWithVideoId:videoId playerVars:playerVars];
```

Comment: That is in Xcode but i want Xamarin so please give me working youtube player in xamarin.

Comment: how to working with YTPlayer in my project please clarify.

Comment: ya its c# but how to working in my project.how to play videos with YTPlayer

Comment: Don't have a readymade solution, you can look at this example (https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/blob/master/Project/youtube-player-ios-example/youtube-player-ios-example/SingleVideoViewController.m) of iOS and extract relevant pointers need to integrate `YTPlayerView`. Even if you are not an XCode expert you can look at the code and extract an overview.

Comment: and Don't forget to add html file in your code, as this YTPlayerView loads this html internally.

Comment: how to call player in my project